# not able to route in angularjs in eclipse

Tags: javascript, angularjs, eclipse

I am not able routing to other page what the problem I dont know please solve my problem.
I am using **Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers**.
Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)
Build id: 20150924-1200

```js
// also include ngRoute for all our routing needs
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

// configure our routes
myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider

  // route for the home page
    .when('#/', {

    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: 'mainController'
  })

  // route for the about page
  .when('#/about', {
    templateUrl: 'about.html',
    controller: 'aboutController'
  })

  // route for the contact page
  .when('#/contact', {
    templateUrl: 'contact.html',
    controller: 'contactController'
  });
});

// create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
myApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  // create a message to display in our view

  $scope.username = 'ranjeet';
  $scope.password = 'singh';

  $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!';
});



myApp.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = 'Look! I am an about page.';
});

myApp.controller('contactController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = 'Contact us! JK. This is just a demo.';
});
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-route.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Angular Routing Example</a>
        </div>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#/">home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#/about"> About</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#/contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <div id="main">

    <div ng-view></div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

file structure of my project :
[[image: file structure of my project][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGVWa.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Your url values in `$routeProvider.when()` should not include `#` which will be set internally if applicable (as by default `html5mode` is disabled by angular router, so angular does use hash location strategy).

Try changing:

```
$routeProvider

  // route for the home page
    .when('#/', {

    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: 'mainController'
  })
```

To

```
$routeProvider

  // route for the home page
    .when('/', { //do remove # from all registered routes
       // ^^ no "#"
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: 'mainController'
  })
```

Comment: You have eagle eyes :p... +1 ..had added few sentence by editing answer

Comment: i did everything with # and only '/ ' eventhogh not working